# Single sign on multiple django sites

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, django-sites

I am working in a django development with **3 sites** (**siteA, siteB, siteC**) under single django code base, where every site have his own domain and own database. Because of the separate databases i have separate users for each site. 

**My question is:** is there any possibility to create a **Single Sign On** to this 3 sites?? 
And if a user is registered in the ***siteA*** and ***siteB*** but not in the ***siteC***, in this case, if the user make login in the ***SiteA*** will be automatically logged in the ***siteB*** (because it is registered in both) but not in the ***siteC***. (like stackexchange.com)

Any suggestion and help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ultimate solution is: OAuth

But if you prefer a short cut, while integrating OAuth into all these Django sites, you can:

> Site A:  Ken, John
>
> Site B: Ken, Joh
>
> Site C: John

We have two sites, and the main sites using some resources from site B but it must be a user on site B. But the two websites do not sync users. Because OAuth was a painful integration, we are doing this:

```
1. Ken login through Site A.
2. As soon as he hits "login", he's redirected to login to Site B and C through iframe login (submit the auth login requests through HTTPS).

3. The iframe login will return cookies of the site trying to login
     - site B
     - site C
4. Since Ken is not a user of Site C, there is no cookies return from Site C.
5. After two iframe logins, you are back to Site A and at this moment, as authenticated user of Site A, ken has at most two cookies:
    - site A
    - site B
```

This is a shortcut but highly insecure. When I say iframe login, I am not saying you will see a iframe with the login form. The request is sent off through request.

It is insecure because the users have to same the same encrypted password :/ and passing cookies around is very easy to attack.